# ANylogic Estimate average queue length in each replicaation

Tags: java, logic, anylogic

Is it possible to take the mean of aa dataset such that I can use that mean in the replication output? What I want is to estimate the queue length from a bock during the process time. I have written QueueBlock.StatsSize.mean();

When I run the replication 10 times I would like the mean of the queue length right now I only get the end queue length..

Answer (score 0):

in your parameter variation experiment, you add a dataset or statistics object called for instance x and in your experiment properties in the after simulation run you add the mean to that x

```
x.add(root.QueueBlock.StatsSize.mean());
```

then you just calculate the mean using `x.mean();`

but what you really want is to collect all the samples in order to make a statistical test to calculate confidence interval for the average